# Disable authentication second step for some authenticators from the first step

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am configuring **Advanced Authentication Configuration** and now i have two steps with three authenticators: 
**First step**: **basic** and my **custom authenticator**. 
**Second step**: for my second step i added **Password Reset Enforcer**
Is it possible to disable second step for my **custom authenticator**? My **WSO2 IS version is 5.10.0**

Comment: What is the type of custom authenticator? Is it a local authenticator or a federated authenticator?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this adaptive script.

```
var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    executeStep(1, {
        onSuccess: function (context) { 
            if (context.steps[1].options[0].authenticator == "BasicAuthenticator") {
                executeStep(2);
            }
        }
    }); 
};
```

Comment: @Askar Sanbayev This won't work because `context.steps[1].options` contains both options you have added as step 1. Not the selected step option.

Comment: According to the current capability of adaptive step we can only find the selected idp of the step(`context.steps[1].idp`). Since Both of your authenticators are local, context.steps[1].idp = "LOCAL". Therefore you can't skip step 2 by validating the authenticated idp.

Comment: Any ideas how to separate it?